# Why is this considered a "good" guarantee of promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

This first guarantee by MDN does not make sense to me.  Can someone explain it using code?

[MDN 3 Guarantees](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Guarantees)

> Callbacks will never be called before the completion of the current
>   run of the JavaScript event loop.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you not understand what it means in general, or are you looking for reasons why it is a good thing?

Comment: I would advise having a read of [this](https://oren.github.io/blog/zalgo.html), amongst several other similar articles online. (Disclaimer: I only just dragged this out of a google search, it was the simplest explanation I could find in a few minutes, but there are probably better ones.) The point of the guarantee you quote is that Promises guarantee that the callback will actually be executed asynchronously, whatever happens - therefore you can never "release Zalgo".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  Promise.resolve(2).then(console.log);
  console.log(1);
```

Will always log 1, then 2.

You can resolve the promise now, somewhen or never. But the `.then` callbacks will always run *after* the synchronous code finished.